# Trasferring data from Google Cloud storage to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, amazon-emr, distcp, data-security

I am transferring data from `Google Cloud Storage` to `AWS S3` using `distcp` in `EMR`(I have made some configuration changes to `EMR` to achieve this). Is the data transfer **secure**? If not, what are the other options?

Comment: Define secure.  It's all SSL - is that secure?

Comment: @stdunbar ; if I understand ; distcp uses SSL? if that is the case, that is what I am looking for.